# How do we list the columns of particular table in Netezza?

Tags: netezza

Result is fetching zero records.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0sz0.png)

Comment: What tool are you using?  Are you able to paste the SQL it generates?

Answer (score 0):

Are you connected to (logged into) the database in which that table exists?

SQL such as this would be a starting point

```
select * from _v_relation_column
where UPPER(name) = 'MY_TABLE'
and UPPER(schema) = 'MY_SCHEMA'
order by attnum;
```

The restriction on schema may not be needed (if you aren't using multiple schemas).

Answer (score 0):

(A) Sometimes we need the column names as headers

`select * from <table> limit 0`

(B) If you want definition of a table ie. showing all columns along with their data types etc (assuming you have nzsql cli)

`nzsql <db> -c "\d <table>"`